# Comparing correlations of variables with different scales

Tags: correlation, scales

I have a couple of variables with different scales - I don't want to use contingency tables so Is there a way to calculate all the correlations with different methods and then compare them?

Comment: Are the variables quantitative, qualitative?

Comment: both - unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use different methods to compare correlations. Unfortunately for the cases with qualitative variables, you'll need contingency tables.

1. Quantitative-quantitative: **Easy!** Spearmean, pearson, and kendall correlation (scales don't matter).
2. Quantitative-qualitative: **Less easy**. You can use a t-test to check the equality of means of the quantitative variable over the modes of the qualitative variable. Or analysis of variance. These are contingency-tables.
3. Qualitative-qualitative: **Less easy**. This is a Chi-2 test. Period.

You won't be able to escape contingency tables.

Comment: @Lara Welcome to Cross Validated :) If the above answer helped, please accept so others know you got the information yuou needed.